# Load jpeg attachment from base64 encoded string

Tags: base64, decode, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a requirement to load jpeg into attachment from a base 64 encoded string by Informatica On Demand. I am doing it by DEC_Base64, It gives type conversion error. My source object is a custom one Call2_vod__c having a long text area field of signature encoded using base64.

Error: CMN_1081 ERROR: Invalid Data Type Conversion

Can someone please suggest a way around?

I can give you details like this. Signature_vod__c is a long textarea(32000) having sample data like this:"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAApAAAACNCAYAAAAAYko8AAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAAAAAEcAAA‌​AoAAAARwAAAEYAA...". I need to decrypt it in jpeg image as content type. I tried it with DEC_BASE64(Signature_vod__c). But data type conversion invalid error was shown

Comment: Hi Marek! Let me know if you need anything more.

Comment: Hi Marek! I do not know how to post screenshot here?I can give you details like this. Signature_vod__c is a long textarea(32000) having sample data like this:"iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAApAAAACNCAYAAAAAYko8AAAAHGlET1QAAAACAAAAAAAAAEcAAAAoAAAARwAAAEYAA...". I need to decrypt it in jpeg image as content type. I tried it with DEC_BASE64(Signature_vod__c). But data type conversion invalid error was shown.

Comment: Can you please clarify why can't you send the base64 encoded string and let the reciver client decode it?

Comment: I am not familiar with Informatica On demand about how to do this decode operation by this and load in attachment